# Help Developing a Season Schedule?

Tags: scheduling

I am trying to create a season schedule for our Knowledge Bowl league (middle school trivia).  I am NOT very mathematical nor a "techie".  Here are my constraints:

1. There are seven schools participating; each school has three teams.  Example:  Tenino Black, Tenino Red, and Tenino White  This means there will be 21 teams total.
2. Teams from the same school cannot play each other.  So each team will play the other 18 teams.
3. There will be seven meets.
4. Each individual meet is made up of three matches in which three teams compete against each other.  Also, each team will complete in 21 matches total.
5. It does not matter if a school is hosting the meet--"Home Advantage" is not a factor.

I know there must be a simple mathematical way to set this up, but I just can't figure it out.  I've tried to just do this randomly, but am quickly approaching insanity.  Please help!  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You already have a constraint violation in your specification. *7 meet ups total with 3 matches at each* that's 21 total debates. However each team is expected to compete in *21 debates*, that is `21 debates * 18 teams / 2 takes two to debate = 189 total debates`. Unfortunately there is no algorithm that can satisfy this problem.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my problem; I think maybe I worded my situation incorrectly.  There are 7 meets, with 3 matches per meet.  So that means each team (Tenino Red for example) will participate in a total of 21 matches because three teams compete against each other in each match.  I know that means that a team should compete against every team two times, and a couple will compete against the same team three times.  (In my old elementary school arithmetic days perhaps referred to as a "remainder"?)  That would be okay with me.  Thanks again!

Comment: Your math still doesn't add up. You say there are 21 teams. We assume there are exactly 2 teams per match. You say there are 21 matches total (7 meets x 3 matches/meet). Given the number of meets/matches, each team can only compete in an average of 2 matches over the entire season. You are afraid that teams will have to compete in multiple matches because there are *too many matches*. In reality, you have the opposite problem: not nearly enough matches. That is the point @Kain0_0 was trying to show you. Also, this question is possibly more appropriate for MathOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to come up with a data structure that naturally enforces your constraints, to the extent possible.

In this case, you might be well-served to start out with a matrix of 21 x 21 cells, each containing an integer. Here's how it would work:

1. Each column represents a team
2. Each row represents a team
3. Each cell represents the meeting of two teams
4. Black out each cell that represents an invalid combination. So

   - Half the cells (diagonally) get immediately blacked out because A vs. B is the same as B vs. A.
   - Any cell where a team would be playing itself gets blacked out
   - Any cell where a team would be playing another team from the same school gets blacked out

Now you have a matrix with a certain number of cells, each of which need to be filled in to identify which meet + match that particular pairing takes place in, perhaps with an integer between 1 and 21. Each integer can only be used X times, where X is the maximum number of teams that can meet simultaneously. You can then iterate over the match/meet numbers, placing them randomly in cells, until all the cells are full. Note that no row or column can contain the same number twice since each team can only play against one team in a given match.

This sort of structure naturally prevents you from assigning the same pairing more than once, so that constraint is automatically satisfied.

I suggest you work this out on paper (or in Excel) manually before you attempt to write the code, so you can see how it would work.

Here's an example matrix with three schools with three teams each.

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much for this--it is a tool I can totally understand and use.  I greatly appreciate your help.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Lets simplify this.

- Assign each school a letter: A to F
- Give each team in that school a number: 1 to 3
- A debate can then be denoted as a combination: (A1, B2, C3)
- (B2, A1, C3) is just the same as (A1, B2, C3) so lets keep them alphabetically sorted.

We can easily write out all of the debate team combinations:

```
(A1, B1, C1), (A2, B1, C1), (A3, B1, C1), (B1, C1, D1), (B2, C1, D1), (B3, C1, D1), (C1, D1, E1), (C2, D1, E1), (C3, D1, E1), (D1, E1, F1), (D2, E1, F1), (D3, E1, F1), (E1, F1, G1), (E2, F1, G1), (E3, F1, G1)
(A1, B1, C2), (A2, B1, C2), (A3, B1, C2), (B1, C1, D2), (B2, C1, D2), (B3, C1, D2), (C1, D1, E2), (C2, D1, E2), (C3, D1, E2), (D1, E1, F2), (D2, E1, F2), (D3, E1, F2), (E1, F1, G2), (E2, F1, G2), (E3, F1, G2)
(A1, B1, C3), (A2, B1, C3), (A3, B1, C3), (B1, C1, D3), (B2, C1, D3), (B3, C1, D3), (C1, D1, E3), (C2, D1, E3), (C3, D1, E3), (D1, E1, F3), (D2, E1, F3), (D3, E1, F3), (E1, F1, G3), (E2, F1, G3), (E3, F1, G3)
(A1, B1, D1), (A2, B1, D1), (A3, B1, D1), (B1, C1, E1), (B2, C1, E1), (B3, C1, E1), (C1, D1, F1), (C2, D1, F1), (C3, D1, F1), (D1, E1, G1), (D2, E1, G1), (D3, E1, G1), (E1, F2, G1), (E2, F2, G1), (E3, F2, G1)
(A1, B1, D2), (A2, B1, D2), (A3, B1, D2), (B1, C1, E2), (B2, C1, E2), (B3, C1, E2), (C1, D1, F2), (C2, D1, F2), (C3, D1, F2), (D1, E1, G2), (D2, E1, G2), (D3, E1, G2), (E1, F2, G2), (E2, F2, G2), (E3, F2, G2)
(A1, B1, D3), (A2, B1, D3), (A3, B1, D3), (B1, C1, E3), (B2, C1, E3), (B3, C1, E3), (C1, D1, F3), (C2, D1, F3), (C3, D1, F3), (D1, E1, G3), (D2, E1, G3), (D3, E1, G3), (E1, F2, G3), (E2, F2, G3), (E3, F2, G3)
(A1, B1, E1), (A2, B1, E1), (A3, B1, E1), (B1, C1, F1), (B2, C1, F1), (B3, C1, F1), (C1, D1, G1), (C2, D1, G1), (C3, D1, G1), (D1, E2, F1), (D2, E2, F1), (D3, E2, F1), (E1, F3, G1), (E2, F3, G1), (E3, F3, G1)
(A1, B1, E2), (A2, B1, E2), (A3, B1, E2), (B1, C1, F2), (B2, C1, F2), (B3, C1, F2), (C1, D1, G2), (C2, D1, G2), (C3, D1, G2), (D1, E2, F2), (D2, E2, F2), (D3, E2, F2), (E1, F3, G2), (E2, F3, G2), (E3, F3, G2)
(A1, B1, E3), (A2, B1, E3), (A3, B1, E3), (B1, C1, F3), (B2, C1, F3), (B3, C1, F3), (C1, D1, G3), (C2, D1, G3), (C3, D1, G3), (D1, E2, F3), (D2, E2, F3), (D3, E2, F3), (E1, F3, G3), (E2, F3, G3), (E3, F3, G3)
(A1, B1, F1), (A2, B1, F1), (A3, B1, F1), (B1, C1, G1), (B2, C1, G1), (B3, C1, G1), (C1, D2, E1), (C2, D2, E1), (C3, D2, E1), (D1, E2, G1), (D2, E2, G1), (D3, E2, G1)
(A1, B1, F2), (A2, B1, F2), (A3, B1, F2), (B1, C1, G2), (B2, C1, G2), (B3, C1, G2), (C1, D2, E2), (C2, D2, E2), (C3, D2, E2), (D1, E2, G2), (D2, E2, G2), (D3, E2, G2)
(A1, B1, F3), (A2, B1, F3), (A3, B1, F3), (B1, C1, G3), (B2, C1, G3), (B3, C1, G3), (C1, D2, E3), (C2, D2, E3), (C3, D2, E3), (D1, E2, G3), (D2, E2, G3), (D3, E2, G3)
(A1, B1, G1), (A2, B1, G1), (A3, B1, G1), (B1, C2, D1), (B2, C2, D1), (B3, C2, D1), (C1, D2, F1), (C2, D2, F1), (C3, D2, F1), (D1, E3, F1), (D2, E3, F1), (D3, E3, F1)
(A1, B1, G2), (A2, B1, G2), (A3, B1, G2), (B1, C2, D2), (B2, C2, D2), (B3, C2, D2), (C1, D2, F2), (C2, D2, F2), (C3, D2, F2), (D1, E3, F2), (D2, E3, F2), (D3, E3, F2)
(A1, B1, G3), (A2, B1, G3), (A3, B1, G3), (B1, C2, D3), (B2, C2, D3), (B3, C2, D3), (C1, D2, F3), (C2, D2, F3), (C3, D2, F3), (D1, E3, F3), (D2, E3, F3), (D3, E3, F3)
(A1, B2, C1), (A2, B2, C1), (A3, B2, C1), (B1, C2, E1), (B2, C2, E1), (B3, C2, E1), (C1, D2, G1), (C2, D2, G1), (C3, D2, G1), (D1, E3, G1), (D2, E3, G1), (D3, E3, G1)
(A1, B2, C2), (A2, B2, C2), (A3, B2, C2), (B1, C2, E2), (B2, C2, E2), (B3, C2, E2), (C1, D2, G2), (C2, D2, G2), (C3, D2, G2), (D1, E3, G2), (D2, E3, G2), (D3, E3, G2)
(A1, B2, C3), (A2, B2, C3), (A3, B2, C3), (B1, C2, E3), (B2, C2, E3), (B3, C2, E3), (C1, D2, G3), (C2, D2, G3), (C3, D2, G3), (D1, E3, G3), (D2, E3, G3), (D3, E3, G3) 
(A1, B2, D1), (A2, B2, D1), (A3, B2, D1), (B1, C2, F1), (B2, C2, F1), (B3, C2, F1), (C1, D3, E1), (C2, D3, E1), (C3, D3, E1)
(A1, B2, D2), (A2, B2, D2), (A3, B2, D2), (B1, C2, F2), (B2, C2, F2), (B3, C2, F2), (C1, D3, E2), (C2, D3, E2), (C3, D3, E2)
(A1, B2, D3), (A2, B2, D3), (A3, B2, D3), (B1, C2, F3), (B2, C2, F3), (B3, C2, F3), (C1, D3, E3), (C2, D3, E3), (C3, D3, E3)
(A1, B2, E1), (A2, B2, E1), (A3, B2, E1), (B1, C2, G1), (B2, C2, G1), (B3, C2, G1), (C1, D3, F1), (C2, D3, F1), (C3, D3, F1)
(A1, B2, E2), (A2, B2, E2), (A3, B2, E2), (B1, C2, G2), (B2, C2, G2), (B3, C2, G2), (C1, D3, F2), (C2, D3, F2), (C3, D3, F2)
(A1, B2, E3), (A2, B2, E3), (A3, B2, E3), (B1, C2, G3), (B2, C2, G3), (B3, C2, G3), (C1, D3, F3), (C2, D3, F3), (C3, D3, F3)
(A1, B2, F1), (A2, B2, F1), (A3, B2, F1), (B1, C3, D1), (B2, C3, D1), (B3, C3, D1), (C1, D3, G1), (C2, D3, G1), (C3, D3, G1)
(A1, B2, F2), (A2, B2, F2), (A3, B2, F2), (B1, C3, D2), (B2, C3, D2), (B3, C3, D2), (C1, D3, G2), (C2, D3, G2), (C3, D3, G2)
(A1, B2, F3), (A2, B2, F3), (A3, B2, F3), (B1, C3, D3), (B2, C3, D3), (B3, C3, D3), (C1, D3, G3), (C2, D3, G3), (C3, D3, G3)
(A1, B2, G1), (A2, B2, G1), (A3, B2, G1), (B1, C3, E1), (B2, C3, E1), (B3, C3, E1)
(A1, B2, G2), (A2, B2, G2), (A3, B2, G2), (B1, C3, E2), (B2, C3, E2), (B3, C3, E2)
(A1, B2, G3), (A2, B2, G3), (A3, B2, G3), (B1, C3, E3), (B2, C3, E3), (B3, C3, E3)
(A1, B3, C1), (A2, B3, C1), (A3, B3, C1), (B1, C3, F1), (B2, C3, F1), (B3, C3, F1)
(A1, B3, C2), (A2, B3, C2), (A3, B3, C2), (B1, C3, F2), (B2, C3, F2), (B3, C3, F2)
(A1, B3, C3), (A2, B3, C3), (A3, B3, C3), (B1, C3, F3), (B2, C3, F3), (B3, C3, F3)
(A1, B3, D1), (A2, B3, D1), (A3, B3, D1), (B1, C3, G1), (B2, C3, G1), (B3, C3, G1)
(A1, B3, D2), (A2, B3, D2), (A3, B3, D2), (B1, C3, G2), (B2, C3, G2), (B3, C3, G2)
(A1, B3, D3), (A2, B3, D3), (A3, B3, D3), (B1, C3, G3), (B2, C3, G3), (B3, C3, G3)  
(A1, B3, E1), (A2, B3, E1), (A3, B3, E1)
(A1, B3, E2), (A2, B3, E2), (A3, B3, E2)
(A1, B3, E3), (A2, B3, E3), (A3, B3, E3)
(A1, B3, F1), (A2, B3, F1), (A3, B3, F1)
(A1, B3, F2), (A2, B3, F2), (A3, B3, F2)
(A1, B3, F3), (A2, B3, F3), (A3, B3, F3)
(A1, B3, G1), (A2, B3, G1), (A3, B3, G1)
(A1, B3, G2), (A2, B3, G2), (A3, B3, G2)
(A1, B3, G3), (A2, B3, G3), (A3, B3, G3)
```

That gives us: 405 unique debate team combinations.

Now there are 21 teams, and debates take 3 teams each, therefore one round at a meet will consist of 7 debates. Over the 7 meets that is: 147 actual debates

So the schedule looks like:

```
                       _1_           _2_           _3_           _4_           _5_           _6_           _7_
Meet 1 - Round 1: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 1 - Round 2: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 1 - Round 3: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 2 - Round 1: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 2 - Round 2: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 2 - Round 3: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 3 - Round 1: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 3 - Round 2: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 3 - Round 3: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 4 - Round 1: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 4 - Round 2: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 4 - Round 3: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 5 - Round 1: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 5 - Round 2: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 5 - Round 3: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 6 - Round 1: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 6 - Round 2: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 6 - Round 3: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 7 - Round 1: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 7 - Round 2: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
Meet 7 - Round 3: (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __), (__, __, __)
```

Now while this is what we want, it is hard to ensure that its valid when written like this.

Also, there are two hidden constraints here:

- a team can only be in a single debate on any given round at any given meet.
- a team must participate in all 3 rounds of a meet.

To make that easier on ourselves we need to do some book keeping too. Each time we fill a debate into the schedule we need to mark the team as occupied on that round at that meet. This way we don't double book, and every team is guaranteed 21 matches.

Note: While not strictly necessary, it also makes sense to mark the given combination of teams as done from the list combinations. With 405 unique debates we don't need to repeat ourselves when scheduling 147 debates.

```
Rounds:
                 | A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | B2 | B3 | C1 | C2 | C3 | D1 | D2 | D3 | E1 | E2 | E3 | F1 | F2 | F3 | G1 | G2 | G3 |
-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
Meet 1 - Round 1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 1 - Round 2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 1 - Round 3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 2 - Round 1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 2 - Round 2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 2 - Round 3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
Meet 3 - Round 1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 3 - Round 2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 3 - Round 3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
Meet 4 - Round 1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 4 - Round 2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 4 - Round 3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
Meet 5 - Round 1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 5 - Round 2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 5 - Round 3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
Meet 6 - Round 1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 6 - Round 2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 6 - Round 3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
Meet 7 - Round 1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 7 - Round 2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Meet 7 - Round 3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
```

Its also nice if we aren't running the same three schools against each other over and over again, nor is it terribly fun if the same two debate teams are constantly debating each other with a third wheel constantly changing.

So we are going to need some histograms to help us avoid these issues...

```
Schools
  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
A | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |
B |   | X | X | X | X | X | X |
C |   |   | X | X | X | X | X |
D |   |   |   | X | X | X | X |
E |   |   |   |   | X | X | X |
F |   |   |   |   |   | X | X |
G |   |   |   |   |   |   | X |

Teams
   | A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | B2 | B3 | C1 | C2 | C3 | D1 | D2 | D3 | E1 | E2 | E3 | F1 | F2 | F3 | G1 | G2 | G3 |
---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
A1 |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
A2 |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  
A3 |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X | 
B1 |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
B2 |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
B3 |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
C1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
C2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
C3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
D1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
D2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
D3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
E1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
E2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
E3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
F1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
F2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
F3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |  X |
G1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |
G2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |
G3 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  X |  X |  X |
```

The `X`'s are on purpose, schools can't face themselves, and school A vs G can be found by looking up school A in the column and school G in the row. Similarly for the teams.

But that amount of information is overwhelming... The canonical way to deal with this is with a cost function.

Its a calculation that takes information from the histograms and tells us how bad that choice is.

What makes for a bad debate choice?

- two schools constantly debating each other.

  - there are three pairs of schools in a debate, eg: (A1, B1, C1) has: AvB, BvC and AvC.
  - lets sum the tallies, eg: if `AvB: 2, BvC: 3 and AvC: 0` that is `2 + 3 + 0 = 5`
- two teams are constantly debating each other.

  - again there are three pairs of teams in a debate, eg: (A1, B1, C1) has: A1vB1, B1vC1 and A1vC1.
  - lets sum the tallies, eg: if `A1vB1: 2, B1vC1: 1 and A1vC1: 0` that is `2 + 1 + 0 = 3`

Following the example through: (A1, B1, C1) then has a cost of `5 + 3 = 8`.

If two debates have the same cost then they are as good a choice as  each other. If one is more "costly" than its a worse choice (it goes against our soft constraints more than another choice does).

It shouldn't be too hard to setup a spreadsheet to automatically give a cost per debate team combination.

Now finally we can describe an algorithm to work through this.

1. Short list debate team combinations

   - Ignore any already picked debate team combination.
   - Ignore any debate team combination which has a team already assigned in the current round. Consult the rounds table to verify this.
   - Calculate the cost of each still available debate team combination.
   - Ignore any debate team combination more costly than the least costly remaining choice.
2. pick a debate team combination from the short list at random. Assign this to the next debate slot in the current meetup/round of the schedule.
3. book keeping

   - Mark the debate team combination as used from the list of debate team combinations
   - mark the teams in the debate team combination as busy in the rounds table.
   - add one to the tally for each school vs school in debate team combination in the schools histogram
   - add one to the tally for each team vs team in debate team combination in the teams histogram
4. repeat until the schedule is full.

---

The first pick is simple, every debate team combination is valid. So pick one and assign it.

The second pick is a bit more difficult. We essentially ignore any combination containing those first three schools. So pick any combination from the remaining four schools.

The third pick is less clear. Obvious the combination will contain the seventh school. But which two other teams will be picked? This is where the cost function shines. It will cost a combination which has a school from our first pick, and one from the second pick along with the left over seventh school as the least costly. This makes sense as otherwise we would be picking two schools that are already competing directly in a debate with each other.

The fourth and further picks on the same round will reduce the number of considered combinations as the pool of available teams to pick from shrinks. This may cause some schools to start to over compete with each other. Don't worry though, the next round will be guided by the cost function to balance this back out as it will prefer to select team combinations which favour under competing schools.

---

You can get a feel for how even handed the schedule is in two ways.

- The first is to look at the histograms after you've built the schedule. If they are relatively flat then its pretty reasonable.
- The second is by calculating the cost for the entire schedule.

  - Simply calculate the cost for each scheduled debate using the histograms tallies and sum them all up.
  - You can make several schedules and compare their relative goodness by picking the one with the lowest cost.

Comment: Oh wow!  This is SO helpful!  And I can totally understand it.  Thank you so much for your help--you made a retired middle school teacher VERY happy today!